# Load sparce NumPy matrix into R

Tags: python, r, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have a numPy sparse matrix saved as .npz file, which I want to load into R.
This is what I tried:

```
library(reticulate)
np <- import("numpy")
npz_train <- np$load('netflix_matrix.npz')
df <- npz_train$f[["data"]]
```

The df length is 103327692, but for

```
npz_train_imgs$f[["shape"]]
[1]   17770 2649429
```

which is a total diffrent size from 103327692.
I know it is a sparse matrix, so how can I read it as one?
I would like to have NAs in the blanks.

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the code for `save_npz` or `load_npz` to see how the sparse matrix is saved and loaded.  The details differ depending on the format.  If it is the common `csr` format, `load` uses: `cls((loaded['data'], loaded['indices'], loaded['indptr']), shape=loaded['shape'])`.  I believe `R` has a sparse format, but you'll have to study its docs to determine how it can be used with attributes like this.

Comment: That `shape` and `data` shape look reasonable for a sparse matrix, with a sparsity of .002.  `data` has the non-zero values of this large array.  What you call 'blanks' are zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
scipy <- import("scipy.sparse")
sparse_mat<- scipy$load_npz('netflix_matrix.npz')
```